# How to get posts by category with hexo?

Tags: javascript, hexo

Messing around with a Hexo blog..  I have a category page that list all the posts in each category. But I want separate page unique to one category. I'm not familiar with the syntax here. How do filter for a category called "featured"?

```
<div class="archives-wrap" style="margin: 0px;">
 <div class="archives-category-wrap">
    <blockquote>
    <% if(site.categories.length) { %>
      <%- list_categories(site.categories) %>
    <% } %>
    </blockquote>
</div>

<% site.categories.sort('name').map(function(category){  %>
<div class="archives-wrap">
    <div class="archive-year-wrap" id="<%= category.name %>">
        <h1 class="archive-category"><%= category.name %></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="archives">
        <% category.posts.sort('-date').map(function(post, i){  %>
            <%- partial('_partial/archive-post', {post: post, index: true}) %>
            <% if (post.subtitle && post.subtitle.length) { %>
                <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                    <%- post.subtitle %>
                </h3>
            <% } %>
        <% }) %>
    </div>
</div>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Hexo either, but I think a simple `IF` statement should do the job:

```
<div class="archives-wrap" style="margin: 0px;">
 <div class="archives-category-wrap">
    <blockquote>
    <% if(site.categories.length) { %>
      <%- list_categories(site.categories) %>
    <% } %>
    </blockquote>
</div>

<% site.categories.sort('name').map(function(category){  %>
    <% if(category.name == 'featured') { %>
        <div class="archives-wrap">
            <div class="archive-year-wrap" id="<%= category.name %>">
                <h1 class="archive-category"><%= category.name %></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="archives">
                <% category.posts.sort('-date').map(function(post, i){  %>
                    <%- partial('_partial/archive-post', {post: post, index: true}) %>
                    <% if (post.subtitle && post.subtitle.length) { %>
                        <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                            <%- post.subtitle %>
                        </h3>
                    <% } %>
                <% }) %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
<% }) %>
```

A more elaborate solution could be to use a filter function before map, but I didn't find such a feature in their documentation.